# How to efficiently process large amount data response from REST API?

Tags: python, rest, hbase, bigdata

One of out client who will be supplying data to us has REST based API. This API will fetch data from client's big data columnar store and will dump data as response to requested query parameters.
We will be issuing queries as below

```
      http://api.example.com/biodataid/xxxxx
```

Challenge is that though response is quite huge though. For given id it contains JSON or XML response with at least 800 - 900 attributes in response for single id. Client is refusing to change service for whatever reason I can't cite here.  In addition , due to some constraints we will get only 4-5 hour window daily to download this data for about 25000 to 100000 ids.

I have read about synchronous vs asynchronous handling of response.  What are options available to design data processing service for efficiently loading to relational database ?  We use python for data processing and mysql as current data ( more recent data ) store and H-Base as backend big data-store (recent and historical data).  Goal is retrieve this data and process and load it either MySQL database or to H-Base store as fast as possible.

If you have built high throughput processing services any pointers will be helpful. Are there any resources for creating such services with example implementation ?

PS -  If this question sounds too high level please comment and I will provide additional details.

I appreciate your response.

Comment: I am not an expert of this topic, but wouldn't an event storage help? You can convert each item to a domain event, and immediately store in an event storage. After that you can use eventual consistency to transform into whatever form your read database support.

Comment: @inf3rno -Thanks. I was also leaning towards dumb data collection and relieving processing ( loading ) on later stage. Wanted to hear from people on SO.

Comment: Most common approach: Use REST with pagination. Let the destination pull the data from the source via HTTP.Get method with the pages requested by the destination as params. Consider a Reactive Approach.